# ASP.NET - have HTTP and HTTPS versions of same-named web pages: is this doable or insane?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, securityswitch

I have been working on a website and originally thought that I could use HTTPS just for logged in users and for the log in process, and use HTTP for non-logged in users. E.g., a logged in user could see custom info on a secure home page, whereas visitors would see an unsecure generic home page, where home page would be like http://example.com or https://example.com (in terms of web address).

I am guessing that I have to make the whole site HTTPS, given that I don't want cookies for "Remember Me" users who are returning to be sent in plain text. It seems that since I migrated from MVC 4 to MVC 5 and Membership based authentication to Identity, that my app no longer reconnects with via "remember me" mode if I return to the HTTP version of the homepage, though does when I go to the HTTPS version.

My question is this: Can I have a secure app for logged in, or returning "remember me" users and at the same time have HTTP page access for non-logged in users?  And if so, how? I have SecuritySwitch and my question is aiming at creating a secure sensibly structured site.

Comment: It'd be easier just to make your site only available over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you, @Dai. Will do that.